# $\sin^3 a\sin(b-c)+\sin^3b\sin(c-a)+\sin^3c\sin(a-b)+\sin(a+b+c)\sin(b-c)\sin(c-a)\sin(a-b)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

> Verify that$$\sin^3 a\sin(b-c)+\sin^3b\sin(c-a)+\sin^3c\sin(a-b)$$
>   $$+\sin(a+b+c)\sin(b-c)\sin(c-a)\sin(a-b)=0.$$

I tried to break $\sin^3a$ into $\sin^2\cdot\sin a$ and use it to make sum with $\sin(b-c)$, but eventually messed up everything. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the angle sum formula to write everything in terms of $\sin(a),\sin(b),\sin(c),\cos(a),\cos(b),\cos(c)$? Together with $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ this should be all you need.

Comment: See https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120925045716AAufnH4

Comment: Archive link^: https://web.archive.org/web/20210417191046/https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120925045716AAufnH4

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{cyc}\sin^3a\sin(b-c)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}(3\sin{a}-\sin3a)\sin(b-c)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{cyc}\left(3\cos(a-b+c)-3\cos(a+b-c)-\cos(3a-b+c)+\cos(3a+b-c)\right).$$
$$\sin(a+b+c)\prod_{cyc}\sin(a-b)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(a+b+c)\sin(b-c)(\cos(2a-b-c)-\cos(b-c))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sin(a+b+c)(-\sin(2c-2a)-\sin(2a-2b)-\sin(2b-2c))=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{4}\sin(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\sin(2b-2c)=-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{cyc}(\cos(3c+a-b)-\cos(3b+a-c))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{cyc}(\cos(3a+c-b)-\cos(3a+b-c))$$
and since 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(\cos(a-b+c)-\cos(a+b-c))=\sum\limits_{cyc}(\cos(b-c+a)-\cos(a+b-c))=0,$$ 
we are done!